# How to hide HTML Page Source in php by detecting the URL

Tags: php, html

I do not care about people viewing my source code, however, I want Bots to avoid coming on to my site and getting through my security. I was hoping to disable page source viewing. To do this, I am using this code:

```
$url= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$needle = "view-source:";
if (strpos($url,$needle)) { echo "You can not see me";}
else {
//The rest of my index page
}
```

The objective here is that if someone tries to view my page source or if a bot tries to, that rather than being able to see it, the code will detect that the page URL is view-source:www.yoururl.com and will display a "Nice try" message in the source instead of the page source. The code above in theory should have worked, but didn't. Any other idea's to try and make this work?

Comment: search engines use bots to crawl your site and index it...so unless you have something super secret on it that you dont want to share... its probably not a good idea.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Only chrome uses view-source as a prefix. You can definitely use .htaccess and robots.txt files to [block bots](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml) from crawling your site though! That is probably the most practical method.

Comment: Well the main reason is because On one of my pages, I created a Captcha system using GD, but, because of the way my site is designed, I needed to include the image src like this: "captcha.php?capnum=3224". I do not want a bot to see that 3224 (Which is randomized in PHP code) and then slip on through and register on the site. I figured the best way to do that is if I could hide the page source.

Comment: You can see what I mean by going to http://sw-bfs.com and going to the register page and then viewing the source and looking for the Captcha image part. I know there are ways to prevent this using sessions and such, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"> or else use robots.txt

Comment: robots does not only mean crawlers...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you could use `mod_rewrite` and a permanent 301 redirect in your .htaccess to hide the `?captcha=xxxx` part of your url, if it is your sole concern.

Comment: Yes, it is my sole concern. How would I do that? It sounds like exactly what I need.

Comment: enable mod_rewrite in apache, then redirect everything through .htaccess RewriteRule. I'm not good enough to give you the exact code but this should be really easy, something like 2 lines of code. You may have a look in SO for that, there are plenty of examples of url rewriting with 301 redirect.

Comment: A `mod_rewrite` can only hide the URL parameters in the address bar, but will do nothing to hide them in his code, which is what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, even if he hid the `?capnum=3224`, the hidden `<input />` would display the captcha number openly in the code.

Comment: This is not what `mod_rewrite` does. It rewrites URLs on *requests* to the web server; it does not (and cannot) modify the output of pages.

Comment: All of you are right in the comments, but as you noticed his question mentionned hiding the code which is actually NOT what he needs to do. url rewriting actually hides the url parameters and that's what he needs.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done, the HTML source code is passed to whoever requests it. You should probably redesign your captcha, as it is not secure from how you described it. Use session variables to store the data and to check against the submitted value on the form processor script.

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned above, I am trying to avoid re-designing the captcha system or using session variables. I tried the session variable the first time I implemented it and it went haywire. The only thing I can think of is maybe split the captcha into two images and try it that way...

Comment: I could, but I am trying to program my site entirely from scratch. That gives me a better opportunity to modify the site if I need to with better control. It also improves my learning experience with PHP and html.

Comment: If you're looking for more learning experience, I still recommend creating your own, more secure version using session variables. It's not too hard to do, and I think you'll learn quite a bit along the way. If you have any questions, just come back to Stack Overflow!

Comment: And from experience, you definitely don't want the headache of dealing with an attack originating from a human, who would have little difficulty bypassing your captcha.

Comment: Well, I am not concerned that a human would attack. I just dont want some bot registering on my site and then SPAMMING my forums.

Comment: I will leave this up to you. Currently it is insecure and cannot be made secure without rewriting the captcha design. I would advise security over saving a few minutes.

Comment: Well Wes, I have a development server where I test new modifications before I post them live on a site. I will try again to mess around with the Sessions variables. However, I had tried for hours with no success before. Hopefully I can get it done the right way. Either way, if you were to go to my site, you would see that I have placed a few precautions in place for SPAM Bots.

Comment: Hopefully this tutorial will help: http://www.code-sucks.com/code/php/template.php?tutorial=basic_captcha.php Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Wes! Appreciate the link! :)